# Why isn't Alt-Tab working for switching windows of the same app?

Tags: macos, keyboard, window-manager

In my MacBook Pro running Lion, I use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch apps, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><sup>1</sup> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> for switching windows within an app.

In my work iMac, also running Lion, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> isn't doing anything, and I can't find any setting for that. Also, I dont remember tweaking anything in the MacBook Pro to get this to work.

*note <sup>1</sup> - <kbd>Alt</kbd> is the same as <kbd>Option</kbd> on most Mac keyboards, but mine just has <kbd>Alt</kbd> printed.*

Comment: Just for the record `Command` + ` (the key above tab) works really well for me.

Comment: This is not default behaviour on your MBP.  Somebody must've changed the default key mapping.

Comment: It's because the dock needs to be killed and restarted, checkout the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/7715/cmd-tab-suddenly-stopped-working-and-my-dock-is-unresponsive-what-do-i-do/7717#7717

Answer (score 34, accepted):

<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shouldn't be assigned to switching windows by default. You could've reassigned it in the Keyboard preferences:

[image]

It could also be handled by some third party app like Witch, LiteSwitch X, or Keyboard Maestro on the MacBook Pro.

Comment: Thanks! I dont remember having done that, but whatever. I reccomend this shortcut, its very convenient to have command + tab and alt + tab so close to one another

Comment: This is not the answer! This is: https://superuser.com/questions/7715/cmd-tab-suddenly-stopped-working-and-my-dock-is-unresponsive-what-do-i-do/7717#7717

Answer (score 41):

Try <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick). That is the default.

Comment: command + ~ does absolutely nothing on my 2015 Macbook Pro.

Comment: Note, however, that it won't cycle to minimized windows.

Comment: Bloody hell, this **cycles** instead of being alternate. What's the command for alternate tab?

Comment: This is the answer: https://superuser.com/questions/7715/cmd-tab-suddenly-stopped-working-and-my-dock-is-unresponsive-what-do-i-do/7717#7717

Answer (score 4):

Mavericks use Command + Tab to switch between the application but if you want to cycle through the different window of same application use this:
Command + Tab + DownArrow it will show all the open windows of the same application which you can select using arrow keys.

Comment: ugh there has to be an easier way to do this...

Comment: found it: https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch :)

Answer (score 4):

Use Hyperswitch.  I just stumbled on this posting now, and did some digging and found this nice "new" app.

https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch

Works well for me (basically turns your mac's application-switching into a windows-style task-switching environment <- much more intuitive especially when working w/ multiple screens/spaces).

Comment: Apple is really behind, why staying blind over the years, this is simple stuff, navigating through Apple OS is a mess, people shouldn't need to pay an extra software to do sth that simple.

Answer (score 2):

> Go to Applications ➔ Utilities ➔ Terminal.app
>
> [type]
>
> ```
> killall -9 Dock
> ```

Reference
https://superuser.com/questions/7715/cmd-tab-suddenly-stopped-working-and-my-dock-is-unresponsive-what-do-i-do/7717#7717

Comment: Not an answer to the question here, but an answer to mine :-)

Answer (score 1):

On german Keyboard Layouts changing windows of an app is mapped to <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> respectively.

Comment: I have a german MBP15 Retina with english keyboard. CMD-~ didn't work, but CMD-shift-< does. CMD-> does other things, though. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, of course I had to add shift: < is a shift character :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried [AltTab](https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/). You can check. Hyperswitch is getting really awkward lately.

[image]